# Can't append options in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong ?

```
var $whatSummary = $("<p></p>");

var remindersContent2 = {
"Variant A": {
    "day": [
        -1,
        0
    ],
    "ids": [
        "D-1",
        "D0"
    ],
    "qm": {
        "a": b
    },
    "msg": {
        "a": b
    }
},
"Variant B": {
    "day": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "ids": [
        "D1",
        "D2"
    ],
    "qm": {
        "x": y
    },
    "msg": {
        "x": y
    }
}
```

}

```
    $whatSummary.append("<select class='js-variantSelectContent'></select>")
    for (var key in remindersContent2) {
      var pkName =_dashUtils.getVariantName(remindersContent2[key]['day'])
      $('.js-variantSelectContent').append($("<option value ='" + key + "'>" + pkName + "</option>"))
    }`
```

By writing above code I want to add a variant selector which will display the data as per the variant pkName. Here $whatSummary is an empty container in which we are appending a selector as per our need.
Here pkName is getting populated properly with a string value like "-1st day to due date" for Variant A and "+1st day to +2nd day" for Variant B respectively. But the options are not getting appended with the pkNames, can someone help?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Where's your HTML? What is `remindersContent2`?

Comment: Are remindersContent2 and _dashUtils defined and populated before executing the code?

Comment: How can we be of help when you haven't provided any information about the actual object that is supposedly supplying data to your posted code? Also, what does .jsp have to do with this question?

Comment: I've modified your code to do not use _dashUtils and it is working fine, check your console maybe there is an error with something else which stops executing your code

Comment: You didn't state what your problem is. "I expect this to happen, but what actually happens is that".

Comment: I have provided a minimal reproducible example, and there is no console error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `$whatSummary` is appended to the DOM, the selector `.js-variantSelectContent` cannot find the select element inside it.

You can store the select element in a separate variable first.

```js
const $select = $("<select class='js-variantSelectContent'/>");
$whatSummary.append($select);
for (const key in remindersContent2) {
    // ...
    $select.append($("<option value ='" + key + "'>" + pkName + "</option>"))
}
// add $whatSummary to the DOM after...
```